# Low level Elastic search not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do Elastic search with sort option. My query is like this:

```
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var query = new
{
    query = new
    {
        term = new { title = "7-0 v Spurs" }
    },
    Sort = new List<ISort>
    {
        new SortField { Field = "releaseFrom", Order = SortOrder.Descending }
    }
};
```

and my search is like this:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
client.Serializer.Serialize(query, stream);
var jsonQuery = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
var qRequest = new SearchRequest(jsonQuery);
var searchResponse = client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<dynamic>>(IndexingService.IndexName, "article_en", qRequest);
```

I am getting the result, but it returns records which does not match the title and also it does not sort.

This is the query which is generated:

```
{ "query": { "term": { "title": "7-0 v Spurs" } }, "sort": [ { "releaseFrom": { "order": "desc" } } ] }
```

Anybody, with suggestion if I miss something here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. 
Used ElasticLowLevelClient instead of ElasticClient. 
Code is like this:

```
var lowlevelClient = new ElasticLowLevelClient(settings);


var stream = new MemoryStream();
    lowlevelClient.Serializer.Serialize(query, stream);
    var jsonQuery = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());



var searchResponse = lowlevelClient.Search< SearchResponse<dynamic>>(IndexingService.IndexName, "article_en", jsonQuery);
```

one change in query also

```
match = new { title = "7-0 v Spurs" }
```